# Javascript code and HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a settings page made of a form with inputs, checkboxes and a form submit.

When I load the page, regardless of my previous saved settings, it shows nothing below `<select class="required-entry">`

How do I edit the javascript code to make it work correctly?

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {      
$('.required-entry').change(function(){    // use class or use $('select')
    if ($(this).val() == "3" || $(this).val() == "2") {
        $("#attach").show();

    } else {
         $("#attach").hide();
    }
});
});
$(function() {      
$('.required-entry').change(function(){    // use class or use $('select')
    if ($(this).val() == "1" || $(this).val() == "3") {
                $("#attach2").show();
    } else {
                     $("#attach2").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select class="required-entry">
<option value="0" selected="true">Show nothing</option>
<option value="2" selected="true">WhatsApp only</option>
<option value="1" selected="true">E-mail only</option>
<option value="3" selected="true">WhatsApp + E-mail</option>
</select>

<div id="attach" style="display:none;" >WhatsApp description</div>
<div id="attach2" style="display:none;" >E-mail description</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't pre-select every option

Comment: Just trigger the `change` event on page load.

Comment: "my previous saved settings" - how do you save these settings? Directly to a file? To a database? The script you've posted is executed only when user changes `#.required-entry`, even then, it's acting according to the current selection, it's not retrieving anything "saved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/zopise/edit?html,js,output)**

You shouldn't pre-select every option and you should trigger the change event on page load;

```js
$(function() {      
  
  $('.required-entry').change(function(){    
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "3" || val == "2") $("#attach").show();
    else  $("#attach").hide();
     
    if (val == "1" || val == "3") $("#attach2").show();
    else $("#attach2").hide();
    
  });
  
  $('.required-entry').trigger('change');
  
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="required-entry">
      <option value="0" selected="true">Show nothing</option>
      <option value="2">WhatsApp only</option>
      <option value="1">E-mail only</option>
      <option value="3">WhatsApp + E-mail</option>
    </select>

    <div id="attach" style="display:none;" >WhatsApp description</div>
    <div id="attach2" style="display:none;" >E-mail description</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to create a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jw4oshp/). It seems to be working correctly. Are you including jQuery? Do you see any errors in your console?

```
$(function() {      
$('.required-entry').change(function(){    // use class or use $('select')
    if ($(this).val() == "3" || $(this).val() == "2") {
        $("#attach").show();

    } else {
         $("#attach").hide();
    }
});
});
$(function() {      
$('.required-entry').change(function(){    // use class or use $('select')
    if ($(this).val() == "1" || $(this).val() == "3") {
                $("#attach2").show();
    } else {
                     $("#attach2").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.